# How to save Matrix data programmatically in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, craft3

How can you programmatically save an entry that has a Matrix field in Craft 3?

(Something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brandonkelly/8149062) for Craft 2)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Saving Matrix fields programmatically got a lot easier in Craft 3 thanks to all the content refactoring.

```php
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\elements\MatrixBlock;

// Figure out the section & entry type
$section = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle('news');
$entryTypes = $section->getEntryTypes();
$entryType = reset($entryTypes);

// Create an entry
$entry = new Entry([
    'sectionId' => $section->id,
    'typeId' => $entryType->id,
    'fieldLayoutId' => $entryType->fieldLayoutId,
    'authorId' => 1,
    'title' => 'My Entry',
    'slug' => 'my-entry',
    'postDate' => new DateTime(),
]);

// Set the custom field values (including Matrix)
$entry->setFieldValues([
    'summary' => 'Some "summary" custom field value...',
    'matrixField' => [
        'new1' => [
            'type' => 'blockTypeHandle',
            'fields' => [
                // the block's custom field values...
            ],
        ],
        'new2' => [
            'type' => 'blockTypeHandle',
            'fields' => [
                // the block's custom field values...
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);

// Save the entry
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
```

Comment:  That still works in Craft CMS 4 (as of writing I am using 4.4.x). Just in case someone is asking if that's only a Craft 3 thing. :)

Answer (score 13):

Just an additional note:

If you want to append certain elements to your matrix field instead of overwriting them all you have to do

#### Update Craft 4.0

there is a new `sortOrder` key that makes my previous answer obsolete.

```php
// grab all existing ids
$existingIds = $element->getFieldValue('matrixField')->ids();
// add a new block to the ids
$existingIds[] = 'new1';

$element->setFieldValue('matrixField', [
    'sortOrder' => $existingIds,
    'blocks' => [
        'new1' => [
            'type' => 'blockTypeHandle',
            'fields' => [
                // the blocks custom field values...
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
// Save the entry
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($element);
```

#### Old answer for Craft 3 (first versions < 3.6)

Just an additional note:

If you want to append certain elements to your matrix field instead of overwriting them all you have to do

```php
/** @var \craft\fields\Matrix $field */
$field = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('matrixField');

// get the existing matrixField Value, keep in mind, this is a Query and not an array
$existingMatrixQuery = $element->getFieldValue('matrixField');

// serialize the data in order to get an array like Brandon Kelly
// created in his answer
$serializedMatrix = $field->serializeValue($existingMatrixQuery, $element);

// append the new blocks to the existing array
$serializedMatrix['new1'] = [
    'type' => 'blockTypeHandle',
    'fields' => [
        // the block's custom field values...
    ]
];

$element->setFieldValue('matrixField', $serializedMatrix);

// Save the entry
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($element);
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks Robin! It's icing on the cake that Brandon has baked. :)