# Push/Add asset to Entry by asset filename

Tags: entries, assets, craft3

I have spreadsheet that i'm parsing and I have available to me a Entry ID and the Asset filename. Can I add the asset to the entry by the filename?

Im targeting the product entry with:

```
$product = Entry::find()->section('products')->id($data[3]);
$productImages = ($product->productImages) ? $product->productImages : array();
$name = explode('?', basename($data[2])); 
$pushImageId = Asset::find()->filename($name[0])->id; // $name[0] = myfilename.jpg
$productImages = array_push($productImages,$pushImageId);
$product->productImages($productImages);
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product);
```

The handle for the asset field is:
`productImages`

So when I run this i get this error:

`Exception: Argument 1 passed to craft\services\Elements::saveElement() must implement interface craft\base\ElementInterface, instance of craft\elements\db\EntryQuery given`

Thanks!

**Solution**

Based on the answer from robin in this question [How to save Asset field of an Entry programmatically in Craft 3](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25305/how-to-save-asset-field-of-an-entry-programmatically-in-craft-3)

It you just need to attach the asset ID's as an array. So i re-wrote the following code to create a new array of the original asset ids plus the new one. And it worked!

```
$product = Entry::find()->section('products')->id($data[3])->one();
$name = explode('?', basename($data[2]));
$pushImageIds = Asset::find()->filename($name[0])->ids(); // $name[0] = myfilename.jpg
$newProductImagesArray = array();
foreach($product->productImages as $image){
    array_push($newProductImagesArray,$image->id);
}
array_push($newProductImagesArray,$pushImageIds[0]);

$product->setFieldValue('productImages',$newProductImagesArray);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($product);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the asset and set it as a field value to your entry

```
$pushImageId = Asset::find()->filename($name[0])->ids();
```

`id` will display the `id` property of your query. You won't fetch any results with it `ids()` will return an array of asset ids

```
$product->setFieldValue ('productImages', $productImages);
```

Will set the relation and finally you can store the element

Edit: and you need to fetch the product as well. Currently you just create the query for it